# Curl create and fill a file on remote ftp without fopen

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I want to create and fill a file on a remote ftp using curl (php) and without using fopen.

I found some example through google but every time they use fopen.
I can't use fopen.

so what I want to do:

> Create the connection with FTP (url, login, password)
>
> Create the file.
>
> Fill the file with some contents.
>
> Close the connection.

Is this possible only using curl ?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: I see no way to do this. This is actually not a question about curl, it is a limitation of the ftp protocol which simply does not offer any feature to handle file _content_. You'd need something like WEBDAV for this.

Comment: @aneesh Drop me a note if you made curl "call a function" on a remote system. It would be the biggest security gap in the history of networking. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this way simple than your request;

You can create the file on **own server** and fill the file with your contents. Than connect FTP with cURL and upload file.

- Ofcourse there is upload limitations, if that limitations can be overcome, you can compress the file (.zip, .rar, etc.) than open on the server.

Otherwise you must look that function, "ftp_put".

Comment: It's actually what I start doing but I finally success to use fopen so  is every thing ok. Thanks for your help !